# Why vector file I/O has this error in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to run file I/O. You want to enter int values one by one for vector and output them.

The input goes in properly, but a strange number is output when outputting. Can you help me?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void saveOrder(vector<int> ex)
{
    ofstream fout("ex.txt");
    if (!fout.is_open()) {
        cerr << "fail" << endl;
        return;
    }
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = ex.begin(); it != ex.end(); it++) {
        fout << *it << " ";
    }
}

vector<int> loadOrder()
{
    vector<int> ex2;

    ifstream fin("ex.txt");

    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        cerr << "fail";
        return ex2;
    }

    while (!fin.eof()) {
        cout << fin.get() << endl;
        ex2.push_back(fin.get());
    }

    return ex2;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> ex;

    ex.push_back(1);
    ex.push_back(2);
    ex.push_back(3);
    saveOrder(ex);

    vector<int> ex3;
    ex3 = loadOrder();

    for (vector<int>::iterator it = ex3.begin(); it != ex3.end(); it++) {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yotxv.png)

Comment: [`fin.get()` returns a character per call](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get), which is not what you want. Do `int x; fin >> x;` to read integers.

Comment: See prev reply and you're calling fin.get() twice once to output to screen and once to put push_back. This is also not what you want.

Comment: Also read [Why is `iostream::eof()` inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Answer (score -1):

Your `loadOrder` function implementation is not correct. [fin.get()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) function reads one character at a time and returns it if its available otherwise it returns EOF.

So your while loop reads two character per loop:

`cout << fin.get() << endl;` display the first character on the console and
`ex2.push_back(fin.get());` push the next *character* on to the vector as an integer.

Also it's not a good idea to use [`fin.eof()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/eof/) in while loop to check for end of file because `fin.eof()` will returns true only after reading the end of the file. So your while loop will try to access past the end of file before it terminates.

You can change `loadOrder` function as follows:

```cpp
vector<int> loadOrder()
{
    vector<int> ex2;

    ifstream fin("ex.txt");

    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        cerr << "fail";
        return ex2;
    }

    int x;
    while (fin >> x) {
        ex2.push_back(x);
    }

    fin.close();
    return ex2;
}
```

Also if you have access to latest C++ compiler, you can use [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) and [automatic type deduction](https://www.educative.io/courses/cpp-fundamentals-for-professionals/3Y8qnP0Kv2n) feature to make your code much more simpler.

For example, to print the vector you can use

```cpp
for(const auto& elem : ex) {
     fout << elem << " ";
}
```

Comment: _"Your loadOrder function implementation is not correct."_ - Perhaps true, but you never mention why.